# how to do multiple hide select option ( yes / or ) dynamically using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This creates 3 select boxes, when i choose one select box as yes option, i want to display only no option on the other two select boxes.  if the user chooses, yes or no , I want to display no as options on the second and third select boxes.

Comment: What creates boxes? Please provide more details and some code that you have attempted.

Comment: 3 select options, when i choose "yes" as any select boxes, i want to hidden "yes" as other 2 select boxes

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this type of functionality,
I hope it will help you.

```
  var selected=$('#select1 option:selected').val();
  $("#select2 option[value='"+selected+"']").prop('disabled', true);
  $("#select3 option[value='"+selected+"']").prop('disabled', true);
```

jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/aa7zyyof/6/

Comment: Great work, thank you ! Now i need that multiple options for the same concept & i need that output must hidden not disabled, i hope you will understand

Comment: Welcome..Now to hide options, you need to replace "$("#select2 option[value='"+selected+"']").prop('disabled', true);"  to  
"$("#select2 option[value='"+selected+"']").hide();"